# Data Structure (or Gem) for Usage Tracking & Metrics

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, data-structures, database-design

### Requirement:

I'm building a Rails application, for which the primary feature is utilised through an API. I want to track use of the API for the object that is called for each user so I can display metrics to the user for each of their objects and also bill them based on total usage.

I'm looking for a data structure or other solution that allows me to track and report on the number of times the API is called for a given resource (in this case the 'Flow' object which belongs_to a user).

### Current Implementation:

In an attempt to solve this, I have added a 'daily_calls' Hash field in my model that has a counter for number of API calls by date. I'd also like to add another level with hours below the day, but I know that this will not be very performant when running aggregated queries (e.g. Calls in the last month).

```
# Flow daily_calls field example (Y => M => D)
{2016=>{12=>{14=>5}}, 2017=>{1=>{9=>6}}}

# Flow daily_calls example with hours (Y => M => D => H)
{2016=>{12=>{14=>{23=>5}}}, 2017=>{1=>{9=>{3=>4,4=>2}}}}
```

Currently I'm updating the count with a method when the API is called and I have some methods for aggregating data for a specific object:

```
class Flow < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  ...

  # Update usage metrics
  def api_called
    update_lifetime_count!
    update_daily_count!
  end

  # Example method for displaying usage
  def calls_in_month(date)
    return 0 unless daily_calls[date.year] && daily_calls[date.year][date.month]
    daily_calls[date.year][date.month].values.sum
  end

end
```

The more I explain the above, the more crazy an approach it sounds! I'm hoping the application will be high volume, so I did not want to create excessive data volumes if it can be helped, though it may be useful in future to save more information around API usage, e.g. geolocation / IP of request.

An alternative approach I am considering is creating an object instance for each hour and incrementing an integer field on that object. Then I could run queries for a time range and sum the integers (which would be significantly easier than all this Hash-work).

### Request:

I suspect this is not the optimal solution, so would like to know the best data structure for this, or if there is a gem that allows the flexibility to track these sorts of user activities and use this information for displaying usage to the user and aggregating usage for reporting.

Some example use cases that it should support:

- Display a usage graph by hour for a given Flow (or a more granular level)
- Display the total number of API calls for a given month for all Flows that belong to a given User
- Report on application usage for all users for a given time period

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be able to use a gem like [public_activity](https://github.com/chaps-io/public_activity) or [paper_trail](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail).

If you use one of those gems, you would be able to query them as needed for the information that you want to show to your user.